# Celery：something questions about celery.events.state.State

Tags: python, celery

when I use

```
state = app.events.State()
print state.Task().as_dict()
```

I just got None, like

```
{u'root_id': None, u'result': None, u'children': [], u'uuid': None, u'clock': 0, u'exchange': None, u'routing_key': None, u'failed': None, u'state': u'PENDING', u'client': None, u'parent_id': None, u'kwargs': None, u'sent': None, u'expires': None, u'parent': None, u'retries': None, u'started': None, u'timestamp': None, u'args': None, u'worker': None, u'rejected': None, u'name': None, u'received': None, u'exception': None, u'revoked': None, u'succeeded': None, u'traceback': None, u'eta': None, u'retried': None, u'runtime': None, u'root': None}
```

any idea? Thanks

Comment: Do you have the celery service running as well? The state will always be pending until the service picks up the task and runs it.

Comment: @Cfreak Yes,my celery is running.When I use flower to monitor,I can see the results.